# Mongo divide the value of the field by the specified amount

Tags: mongodb, updating, divide

I use `$mul` operator in update for multiplies field value

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $mul: { price: NumberDecimal("1.25"), qty: 2 } }
)
```

now how can divide field ?

`Mongodb` [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) not exist `$div` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mathematical point of view you can still use `$mul` to divide since there's an inverse relationship between those two operations. For instance:

```
var divideBy = 2;
var multiplyBy = 1/divideBy;

db.products.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $mul: { price: multiplyBy } }
)
```

You'll get the same result as for missing `$div` operator

Comment: How can ciel divide value and store ?(round to up)

Comment: In addition. You can use `{ $mul: { price: NumberInt(multiplyBy) } }` to get an integer number.

Answer (score 3):

Use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

Internal field as input:

```
db.products.update(
  { _id: 1 },
  [{ $set: { price: { $divide: ["$price", "$qty"] } } }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VQJcgDKKykt)

External field as input:

```
var qty = 2;
db.products.update(
  { _id: 1 },
  [{ $set: { price: { $divide: ["$price", qty] } } }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8OQa87_c1a7)